# Clarifying the square integral conditions about stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Define $I(X)=\int_{0}^{T}X(s)dB(s)$ and we see that $E(I(X)^2)=E\int_{0}^{T}X^2(s)ds.$ If $E(I(X)^2)=0$, then $\int_{0}^{T}X^2(s)ds=0$ and it should be $X(s)=0$ a.s. for any $0\leq s\leq T$. But there is a counterexample $X(s)=1_{[0,a]}(s)+1_{(a,\tau]}(s)\frac{1}{T-s},$ where $\tau=inf\{t:t\geq a, \int_{a}^{t}\frac{1}{T-s}dB(s)=-B(a)\}$, which was taught in class. It has $I(X)=0$ but $X\neq 0$.

The homework states that $\int_{0}^{t}X(s)dB(s)=0$ for any $t\in [0,T]$ implies $X=0$. Is it safe to use the square integral approach similarly mentioned above? Or is there any conditions I'm missing?

Comment: Should your definition maybe be $I(X) = \int_0^\infty X(s)dB(s)$?  Otherwise, I don't see how one can conclude $I(X) = 0$ for all $T$ - it looks like we just have $I(X) = 0$ for $T \ge \tau$.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I misunderstood: One can show $\tau \le T$.  The condition $\mathbb{E}[I(X)^2] = 0$ does not imply $X(s) = 0$ for all $s$, as the counterexample shows.  The reason is that the identity $\mathbb{E}[I(X)^2] = \mathbb{E}[\int_0^T X(s)^2ds]$ you referenced is only true *provided both sides are finite*.  In the counterexample you showed, we have $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^T X(s)^2ds] = \infty$, so it does not need to equal $\mathbb{E}[I(X)^2]$.

To show that the correct condition is $\int_0^t X(s)dB(s) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,T]$ implies $X(s) = 0$ for all $s \in [0,T]$, the square integral approach won't work for the same reason as it didn't for the earlier counterexample.  Instead, I would suggest using that a constant martingale has a quadratic variation of $0$.

Comment: I also know that the quadratic variation $\int XdB,\int X dB](t)=\int_{0}^{t}X^2 (s)ds=0$, is it  enough to show $X=0$?

Comment: @Tobikawaii Yes, if $\int_0^t X(s)^2ds = 0$, then $X(s) = 0$ for a.e. $s \in [0,t]$.